# How does/would the following snippet work for generation of an AST?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, bison, compiler-theory, abstract-syntax-tree

We're writing a compiler for Al Aho's compilers class, and we're considering the following code for the generation of our AST. Here is some background. We want to implement scoping rules as a stack of name-id mappings, and we want to push a set of mappings onto the stack before we go in and generate the nodes for the declarations.

```
compound_statement : {pushScope();} statement_list {popScope();}
```

So then, here is my question. How does this work? When will this code get executed? Does it get executed when this production is reduced by the parser? Which part happens when? Should I just go to office hours to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question talks about building AST nodes, but the body of your explanation talks apparantly about symbol tables. These ideas are not the same!   The AST represents the structure of the program.  Symbol tables represent inferences about what names are visible where, and what types they have.

Following your symbol table focus, your notion of pushing the current scope as you "enter" a block, and popping it as you "exit", is conceptually right, as it abstractly achieves new-scope-per-block.

I don't think you can make YACC do what you said, as I'm not sure you can attach a semantic action at any point in a grammar rule. I believe you can only attach actions to the rule as a whole, and that action will only run when the rule has been recognized ("reduced").    So if you really wanted to do this, you'd want to bend the grammar to create opportunities to insert semantic actions.  You can do this by rewriting your rules (following your style, I don't think this is actually valid YACC syntax):

```
  compound_statement : block_start statement_list block_end ;
  block_start = '{' pushScope() ;
  block_end = '}' popScope();
```

I added actions to block start and end symmetrically, but you can be a little more, um, parsimonious (grin):

```
  compound_statement : block_start statement_list '}' popScope() ;
  block_start = '{' pushScope() ;
```

The real secret here was creating a reduction/semantic action execution opportunity after you enter the block, by adding a sub-rule to the original rule.   I've often done this using an empty rule:

```
  compound_statement : '{' compound_statement_sub_rule block_start statement_list '}' popScope() ;
  compound_statement_sub_rule = pushScope() ;
```

Having shown sort of how to do this, I don't think you want to do this at all. What you are doing is tangling semantics with the parsing process.  If you go down this path, you'll find yourself decorating the rest of the grammar with complex actions for creating/lookup up identifiers.   It is generally better to use the semantic actions to simply build a syntax tree, and then after parsing is complete, walk the syntax tree to implement your symbol table construction/identifier lookup.

I'd go to office hours and ask as many questions as you can think of, whether you thought they were dumb or not.  It will pay off handsomely.

Comment: -1 making empty rules like this manually is pointless, as yacc will do all the heavy lifting for you if you let it.  In addition, the whole point of syntax directed translation (Aho's book) is to avoid the overhead of creating a parse tree and traversing it in a separate pass, so if this really is for Aho's class, you might not want to do that...

Comment: @Chris Dodd: So you are saying that yacc will insert dummy rules with semantic actions for you? OK. Most LALR parser generators I've seen do not (its so rare that the extra tooling seems unnecessary). Regarding "syntax directed translation", you are right, if that's what they are doing they'll have to weave all the stuff together. A reasonable person would interpret OP's problem statement "we're considering the following code for the generation of our AST" as indicating they were not doing syntax directed translation. Nor is "Aho's book" entirely about syntax-directed translation.

Answer (score 0):

When you stick an action into the 'middle' of a rule in yacc, it actualy creates a new hidden non-terminal for the action and executes the rule when the hidden non-terminal is reduced.  So your rule:

```
compound_statement : {pushScope();} statement_list {popScope();} ;
```

is equvalent to:

```
compound_statement : hidden_rule statement_list {popScope();} ;
hidden_rule : {pushScope();} ;
```

with the addition that yacc will properly modify $n references in the action so they refer to the right thing.

So the `pushScope` will be executed when `hidden_rule` is reduced (which is before any statement in the `statement_list` is reduced), while the popScope is executed after all the statements are reduced, so this will in fact do exactly what you want.

Comment: A nit: the way the rule is written, the pushScope will happen regardless of whether a statement_list is encountered. That's surely not what the OP wants; he needs to ensure that the start of a statement list (I'm guessing he meant "block") has been processed and that there are no other reductions. My answer included the necessary '{' ... '}' tokens to ensure this, although my Yacc syntax was probably slightly off.